# Android ImageView - Get coordinates of tap (click) regardless of scroll location or zoom scale

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, coordinates

**Background:**
I have an ImageView that I've modified to be scrollable (drag) and zoom-able (pinch zoom). I used the exact technique mentioned in the "Hello, Android" 3rd edition book that can also be found [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=content;siu-container). This technique uses matrix transformation to handle both scrolling and zooming.

**My Problem:**
When a user taps on the image, I want the coordinates of that tap in relation to the image itself, regardless of how the image has been scrolled or magnified. For instance, if my image is 1000x2000 and I scroll and zoom the image. Then I tap on the image at a certain point, I want to know what that point is in relation to the 1000x2000, not just the screen area. How can I do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found a solution to this using bits of info I've pieced together from other questions on this site. To give back to the community, I figured it was only right to share what I learned. Hope this helps somebody:

```
// Get the values of the matrix
float[] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);

// values[2] and values[5] are the x,y coordinates of the top left corner of the drawable image, regardless of the zoom factor.
// values[0] and values[4] are the zoom factors for the image's width and height respectively. If you zoom at the same factor, these should both be the same value.

// event is the touch event for MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
float relativeX = (event.getX() - values[2]) / values[0];
float relativeY = (event.getY() - values[5]) / values[4];
```

Thanks to these sources: 
[source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap) and [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286174/getting-coordinates-and-width-height-from-a-matrix)

Comment: can you please post how the zoom factor is calculated?I'd like to understand if it could be both smaller and bigger than 1 (obviously not at the same time...).

Comment: So helpful for me. Kudos!

Comment: "`Hope this helps somebody`" - absolutely

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Can u please tell what is  `matrix` in this solution. How do you get `matrix`

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 2):

You can also calculate the inverse matrix and use the mapPoints() method:

```
 // Get the inverse matrix
 Matrix inverseMatrix = new Matrix();
 matrix.invert(inverseMatrix);

 // Transform to relative coordinates
 float[] point = new float[2];
 point[0] = e.getX();
 point[1] = e.getY();
 inverseMatrix.mapPoints(point);
```