# Android : How to get Coordinates X,Y of Image after Zoom and Pan

Tags: android, get, zooming, coordinates

I'm developing an application with Zoom and Pan Image..Now, i need to get Coordinates X,y Of Image Each when User Touch Image ( after Zoom and Pan ), Not coordinates of Screen such as method event.getX and event.getX..help me..Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but i was facing the same problem, this actually did the trick.

[Android ImageView - Get coordinates of tap (click) regardless of scroll location or zoom scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002298/android-imageview-get-coordinates-of-tap-click-regardless-of-scroll-location)

Answer (score 1):

please use this formulla to convert actaull coordinates

```
   float curX = (event.getX() / scale) - (left * scale);
    float curY = (event.getY() / scale) - (top * scale);

     mCanvas.drawCircle(((curX / scale)), ((curY / scale)),
                    width / 2 / scale, mPaint);
```

Comment: thanks Ramesh Solanki ! but i don't understand What's left and top value ?

Comment: left and top values are the translate points of image.  means when u zoom image , the left and top position of image are also changed.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh Solanki ! i solved this....But Use Matrix When Drag, i feel Image move at Hight Speed out of screen and not fling..how can i fix this ?