# How to get x and y coordinates of image inside an imageview in android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, coordinates

I'm stuck in this problem.  I have an `imageView` and I would like to get a position of my touch only inside the image. When I touch out of image I must display `x=0` and `y=0`. In this app I must know resize, zoom and rotate the image, there functions are fixed, but I have problem with the coordinates of image only inside the image.

Here is a link, what I mean [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/exampledz.png/)

This is a same problem what I try to solve: [How to get Coordinates X,Y of Image after Zoom and Pan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093429/android-how-to-get-coordinates-x-y-of-image-after-zoom-and-pan?s=d0f1ef64-d0d7-497b-aae8-824fe8027177#new-answer)

Thanks a lot.

Ondrej

Here is my code:

```
public class Sample extends Activity{
        static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    int[] location = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        final Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.mapa);
        image.setImageBitmap(icon);



        image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                final ImageView view = (ImageView) v;


                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
                {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    mode = DRAG;
                    RectF r = new RectF();
                    matrix.mapRect(r);

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG)
                    {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                event.getY() - start.y);
                    } else if (mode == ZOOM)
                    {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f)
                        {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    if (oldDist > 10f)
                    {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                    }
                    break;

                }

                // Perform the transformation
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
```

And main.xml looks like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix" >
    </ImageView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're asking, but I'll try to answer anyway. It sounds like you want to use `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` to get the **touch position** on the screen and not on the view. You may also have to **override** the `onTouchEvent` method for whatever is outside of the `ImageView`.

Comment: Hi Andi, firstly, thanks a lot for your reaction to my answer, sorry for my english, and a problem is this: when I zoom out an image, is smaller than a screen and the coords x=0 and y=0 must be in a top left corner of image, and a touch out of image or around of image we are not interested. I try to make an image, here is a link [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/exampledz.png/)

Comment: In the onTouchEvent() method of the ImageView, you are calling getX() and getY(), correct? I'm saying, you should try getRawX() and getRawY() instead. This will let you read touch coordinates that are scaled to the display size. In other words, getRawX and getRawY will tell you which pixel on the overall screen you are touching. If you use getRawX and getRawY the only time you will see X = 0 and Y = 0 is if you touch the top left corner of the screen. However, in order to get touch events outside of the ImageView, you will need to override onTouchEvent() of the layout that holds the imageview.

Comment: yes, it is a good point, but i would like to get a position of image after zoom or pan, no position of screen like getX() or getY(). this is a same problem what I have [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093429/android-how-to-get-coordinates-x-y-of-image-after-zoom-and-pan?s=d0f1ef64-d0d7-497b-aae8-824fe8027177#new-answer), but I dont understand hot to get a scale or left and top variable

Comment: I see, I think I understand you now. Have you tried to use ImageView.getLocationOnScreen(int[])? Or ImageView.getTop() and ImageView.getLeft()? If this isn't what you're trying to do, please try to explain more :)

Comment: yes, I tried these methods, but getLocationOnSreen returns always zero values and getTop and getLeft always return the same value, in this case zero values, because when open the app, the image is in the top left corner

Answer (score -2):

have a look on

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, but it is very widely.I try to solve same problem like this: [How to get Coordinates X,Y of Image after Zoom and Pan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093429/android-how-to-get-coordinates-x-y-of-image-after-zoom-and-pan?s=d0f1ef64-d0d7-497b-aae8-824fe8027177#new-answer), but I dont understand how get a scale and a left and top variables. thanks