# Correspondence between ImageView coordinates and Bitmap Pixels - Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-image

In my application I want the user to be able to select some content of an Image contained inside an `ImageView`.

To select the content I subclassed the `ImageView` class making it implement the `OnTouchListener` so to draw over it a rectangle with borders decided by the user.

Here is an example of the result of the drawing (to have an idea of how it works you can think of it as when you click with the mouse on your desktop and drag the mouse):

[image]

Now I need to determine which **pixels** of the `Bitmap` image correspond to the selected part. It's kind of easy to determine which are the points of the `ImageView` belonging to the rectangle, but I don't know how to get the correspondent pixels, since the `ImageView` has a different aspect ratio than the original image.

I followed the approach described [especially here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap), [but also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002298/android-imageview-get-coordinates-of-tap-click-regardless-of-scroll-location), but am not fully satisfied because in my opinion the correspondence made is 1 on 1 between pixels and points on the `ImageView` and does not give me all the correspondent pixels on the original image to the selected area.

Calling `hoveredRect` the rectangle on the `ImageView` the points inside of it are:

```
class Point {
    float x, y;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}

Vector<Point> pointsInRect = new Vector<Point>();

for( int x = hoveredRect.left; x <= hoveredRect.right; x++ ){
    for( int y = hoveredRect.top; y <= hoveredRect.bottom; y++ ){

        Point pointInRect = new Point();
        pointInRect.x = x;
        pointInRect.y = y;
        pointsInRect.add(pointInRect);
    }   
}
```

How can I obtain a `Vector<Pixels> pixelsInImage` containing the correspondent pixels of the `Bitmap` image?

---

**ADDED EXPLANATIONS**

I'll explain a little better the context of my issue:

> I need to do some image processing on the selected part, and want to
>   be sure that all the pixels in the rectangle get processed.
>
> The image processing will be done on a server but it needs to know exactly which
>   pixels to process. Server works with image with real dimensions,
>   android app just tells which pixels to process to the server by passing a vector
>   containing the pixel coordinates

And why I don't like the solutions proposed in the links above:

> The answers given transform coordinates with a 1 to 1 fashion. This approach clearly is 
>   not valid for my task, since an area of say 50 points in the `ImageView` of a certain 
>   size on the screen cannot correspond to an area of the same number of pixels in the real 
>   image, but should consider the different aspect ratio.

As example this is the area that should be selected if the image is smaller than the `ImageView` shown on the app:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I see the reason you don't use the approach in your first link. Even assuming there are more pixels than points, it gives you the nearest pixel. I guess you could change them to floats to get sub-pixel values, but I don't see how it could get any closer. Maybe I'm not understanding the issue?

Comment: I need to do some image processing on the selected part, and want to be sure that all the pixels in the rectangle get processed. The image processing will happen on a server but it needs to know exactly which pixels to process. Server works with image with real dimensions, android app just tells which pixels to process.

Comment: Well, to make sure you grab all-inclusive pixels, I'd use the scaling approach and `floor()` the left/top values, and `ceil()` the right/bottom, so at most you will process one extra pixel on each side. It *will* get you the nearest pixel, how you round it will determine which way it goes when you end up with float values.

Comment: @Geobits - I'm kind of a newbie, would you mind being a little more specific for helping me understand?If you could post an answer it would really help me a lot!thks anyway...

Comment: I would say, that you only calculate the points, and round using floor or ceil like Geobits says, if you want to get all pixels inclive. And you send only the 4 points to the server. The server can then loop and generate the pixel array, that's something you should not do on the client, unless you have to use it in the client.

Comment: @Ixx - can you please explain me what you and geobit mean by using floor or ceil? I do not need to do the calculation on the client app...I just thought it would be the same

Comment: It's only about your requirement about ensuring that all pixels inside the rectangle of the big image are also contained in the small one. So for the coordinates which are at the left or at the top, you round using floor, and for the ones at the right or bottom, you round using ceil. floor rounds to the lowest integer and ceil to the highest. This way you don't lose any pixels inside of the rectangle's area due to rounding. You get always an area which is equal or bigger.

Comment: But forget about floor and ceil at the beginning, it's probably enough if you just round to the lowest integer (casting to int already does this).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Matteo,

It seems this is more a question of how much error you can (subjectively) tolerate in which pixels you send to the server. The fact remains that for any aspect ratio that does not come out to a nice neat integer, you have to decide which direction to 'push' your selection box.

The solutions you linked to are perfectly good solutions. You have to ask yourself: Will the user notice if the image I process is one pixel off from the selection box shown on the screen? My guess is probably not. I can't imagine the user will have that sort of pixel precision anyways when selecting a rectangle with their big fat finger on a touchscreen :D

Since this is the case, I would just let the `floor()`-ing that occurs when casting to an integer take care of which pixels you end up passing to the server.

Let's look at an example.

Let's define the width and height of our ImageView and Bitmap to be:

```
ImageViewWidth = 400, ImageViewHeight = 150
BitmapWidth = 176, BitmapHeight = 65
```

Then the aspect ratios you will use to convert your selection box between them will be:

```
WidthRatio = BitmapWidth / ImageViewWidth = 175 / 400 = 0.44
HeightRatio = BitmapHeight / ImageViewHeight = 65 / 150 = 0.44
```

Some nice ugly numbers. Whatever pixel I am on in the ImageView will correspond to a pixel in the Bitmap like so:

```
BitmapPixelX = ImageViewPixelX * WidthRatio
BitmapPixelY = ImageViewPixelY * HeightRatio
```

Now, I put this Bitmap on the screen in my ImageView for the user to select a rectangle, and the user selects a rectangle with top-left and bottom-right coordinates in the ImageView as such:

```
RectTopLeftX = 271, RectTopLeftY = 19
RectBottomRightX = 313, RectBottomRightY = 42
```

How do I determine which pixels in the Bitmap these correspond to? Easy. The ratios we determined earlier. Let's look at just the top-left coordinates for now.

```
RectTopLeftX * WidthRatio = 271 * .44 = 119.24
RectTopLeftY * HeightRatio = 19 * .44 = 8.36
```

For RectTopLeftX, we find ourselves at a BitmapPixelX value of 119, and then about a quarter of a way into the pixel. Well, if we `floor()` this value and the corresponding BitmapPixelY value of 8.36, we will be sending pixel `(119, 8)` to the server for processing. If we were to `ceil()` these values, we will be sending pixel (120, 9) to the server for processing. **This is the part that is entirely up to you.**

You will (nearly) always land in some fractional part of a pixel. Whether you send the pixel you land in, or the one next to it is your call. I would say that this is going to be entirely unnoticeable by your user, and so to reiterate, just let the `floor()`-ing that occurs when casting to an integer take care of it.

Hope that helps!

### [EDIT]

Upon reading the question again more slowly, I think I better understand what you are asking/confused about. I will use my example above to illustrate.

You are saying that there are 176 pixels in the Bitmap, and 400 pixels in the ImageView. Therefore, the mapping from one to the other is not 1:1, and this will cause problems when figuring out what pixels to pull out for processing.

But it doesn't! When you convert the coordinates of the rectangle bounds in the ImageView to coordinates in the Bitmap, you're simply giving the **range of pixels** to iterate over ***in the Bitmap.*** It's not a description of how each individual pixel in the ImageView maps to a corresponding pixel in the Bitmap.

I hope that clears up my confusion about your confusion.

Comment: I really liked your answer!It was very useful, especially the final remarks about our confusions... ;) thks a lot for spending some time in understanding my point!you deserved the bounty ;D

Answer (score 2):

This is solvable with very simple maths, your rectangle has 4 points p1, p2, p3, p4, with coordinates x, y, relative to the ImageView.

You also know the dimensions of the original image.

Now if p1.x, for example, is 50, in an ImageView which is 200 px wide, you get relation of 50 / 200 = 0.25

If your original image is 100 px wide, your point p1.x would be located at 100 * 0.25 = 25 px

Can be expressed:

> 50 -> 200
>
> ? -> 100

And calculated:

> ? = 100 * 50 / 200

You do this for each point, for each dimension x, y, and then you get the 4 points of the rectangle in the original image.

Now if you iterate using these calculated points you should get the pixels of the rectangle in the original image.

Comment: thks for answer, but this is more or less what already stated in the questions I linked. I am afraid that these solutions have 2 problems: 1) when pixels divisions do not give integer result (ex. pixel 100 * 0.33 = pixel?? if aspect ratio is 1/3) 2) a rectangle with say 50 pixels in the smaller image selecting a part of it to be contain the same part in the bigger image must have more than 50 pixels in the big image, so correspondence 1 on 1 is not ok. Let me know if I have to explain better

Comment: The first question: Calculate everything using float and double, and round the coordinates in the original image to the nearest integer (this will be a bit inaccurate, but it looks like you app can tolerate this?). The second question: This is not 1:1 between pixels, if this was the case you would get the same size for the rectangle in the original image and in the ImageView and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: check the updates in my question!I'll think about what you said...thks ;D

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm assuming that you've placed something inside your image view. Do this inside onCreate:

```
ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
TextView coordinates=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)Map.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

And this inside onTouch:

```
coordinates.setText("Touch coordinates:"+String.valueOf(event.getX())+"x"+String.valueOf(event.getY()));
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
```

Now you have the particular pixel you want.