# Mapping preview image coordinates to picture image coordinates

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, android-view

I have used my Google-fu to no avail on this question. My problem: I have an Android app, which overlays an ellipse on top of the `Camera` preview using the `EllipseView` class below:

```
public class EllipseView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public EllipseView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setAlpha(0x60);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Point canvasCenter = new Point(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        RectF oval = new RectF(canvasCenter.x - 100, canvasCenter.y - 75, canvasCenter.x + 100, canvasCenter.y + 75);

        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvasCenter.x, canvasCenter.y, 5, paint);
    }

}
```

Is it possible to find the same `oval` coordinates in the picture that gets captured? Or, am I going to have to manually determine the transform?

Answer (score 0):

- Get the width and height of your preview surface
- Get the width and height of the bitmap taken
- Divide one by the other to get the width conversion and height conversion ratios
- Find the location of the ellipse in the preview surface
- Use the ratios to calculate where it would be on the bitmap taken
- Do your magic...

  More detailed help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334984/correspondence-between-imageview-coordinates-and-bitmap-pixels-android)