# Android : How to convert view to Bitmap, without capturing background screen

Tags: android, image, bitmap, screen

For my application, i have used pinch zoom feature by adapting from the tutorial and creating a custom view http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

Right now i'm working on capturing the zoomed image as bitmap.

Partially I was able to get the bitmap by making use of

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalView.getDrawingCache());
setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Using this approach, I'm getting both the zoomed image and the screen background.

Is there any way to capture only the zoomed image as a bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having searched a lot, I found a 'Temporary' solution in the same Community & also thanks for the code from 'weakwire' provided in the same post.

[Getting coordinates and width/height from a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286174/getting-coordinates-and-width-height-from-a-matrix)

Idea is simple, all i have do is remove the background screen from the scaled image by cropping. Code is bit lengthy, but worked for me.

1. First get the Original Bitmap size

   ```
   float imgWidth = imgBitmap.getWidth()   
   float imgHeight = imgBitmap.getHeight()
   ```
2. Obtain the matrix ( pinch zoom feature used in my application uses matrix 'trick') values, used to scale the image  and get the scaledWidth & scaledHeight of the original image.

   ```
   float[] values = new float[9];
   matrix.getValues(values);
   float globalX = values[2];
   float globalY = values[5];
   float scaledWidth = values[0]*imgWidth;
   float scaledHeight = values[4]*imgHeight;   

   // If zoomed Image gets out of screen, I'm trying to crop the image available in the screen by considering image from (0,0)

   if(globalX<0)
   globalX = 0;

   if(globalY<0)
   globalY = 0;
   ```
3. Finally capture the View and crop the background
       In my case ("finalView" is the custom View name, where pinch zooming happens)

   ```
   setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
   destroyDrawingCache();
   finalView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalView.getDrawingCache());
   finalView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);    

   //Final Image Width &  Height

   int finalWidth = Math.min((int)width,(int)finalView.getWidth());
   int finalHeight = Math.min((int)height,(int)finalView.getHeight());
   ```

   // crop to get the scaled image

   ```
    Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, (int)globalX, (int)globalY, finalWidth ,finalHeight);
   ```

Though this is a temporary solution, it works for me. If there is any alternate solution, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)
finalView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalView.getDrawingCache());
finalView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: try to destroyDrawingCache after the first line please

Comment: I have tried setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);   destroyDrawingCache();

Comment: but same result, getting background in the bitmap.. .

Answer (score 0):

This original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595919/578309), just replace the setting background part. Hopefully it helps

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    if (view == null) return null;
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    // draw white background on the canvas
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```